# Use Pandas to Check for Gap Fill in Stock Prices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm wanting to put a 1 in the column `'Gap Fill?'` if there's a `'1'` in the `'Gap Down?'` column, AND the max of `'Highs'` starting from today and going 5 days into the future, or `(.shift(-5))` is `>=` yesterday's `'Adj Close'` or `(.shift(-1))`.

Here's my code to recreate and come up with a solution:

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 

# initialize list of lists 
data = [[5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4],
         [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4],
         [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4],
         [3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 10, 3, 4],
         [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4],
         [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4],
         [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4],
         [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4]
         ] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Adj Close']) 

# Now apply a new column and put a 1 if today's opened is less than yesterday's Adj Close
df['Gap Down?'] = 0

df.loc[df['Open'] < df['Adj Close'].shift(1), 'Gap Down?'] = 1
df.loc[df['Open'] >= df['Adj Close'].shift(1), 'Gap Down?'] = 0

# print the new dataframe
print(df)

# Now make a new column that puts a 1 if the highest price in the High column from today
# and FORWARD (future) 5 days becomes >= yesterday's close
df['Gap Fill?'] = 0
```

This currently gives the output:

```
    Open  High  Low  Adj Close  Gap Down?
0      5    10    3          4          0
1      5    10    3          4          0
2      5    10    3          4          0
3      5    10    3          4          0
4      5    10    3          4          0
5      5    10    3          4          0
6      5    10    3          4          0
7      5    10    3          4          0
8      5    10    3          4          0     <- Yesterday's Adj Close was 4
9      3     3    3          3          1     <- Today opened at 3 so there's been a gap down
10     3     3    3          3          0
11     3    10    3          4          0     <- Here is when the High went >= 4, and it's within 5 days of the open price in question
12     5    10    3          4          0
13     5    10    3          4          0
14     5    10    3          4          0
15     5    10    3          4          0
16     5    10    3          4          0
17     5    10    3          4          0
18     5    10    3          4          0
19     5    10    3          4          0
20     5    10    3          4          0
21     5    10    3          4          0
22     5    10    3          4          0
23     5    10    3          4          0
```

And I would like to end up with this:

```
    Open  High  Low  Adj Close  Gap Down? Gap Fill?
0      5    10    3          4          0         0
1      5    10    3          4          0         0
2      5    10    3          4          0         0
3      5    10    3          4          0         0
4      5    10    3          4          0         0
5      5    10    3          4          0         0
6      5    10    3          4          0         0
7      5    10    3          4          0         0
8      5    10    3          4          0         0
9      3     3    3          3          1         1   <- ... but the 1 should go here
10     3     3    3          3          0         0
11     3    10    3          4          0         0   <- The gap fill happened here two days later...
12     5    10    3          4          0         0
13     5    10    3          4          0         0
14     5    10    3          4          0         0
15     5    10    3          4          0         0
16     5    10    3          4          0         0
17     5    10    3          4          0         0
18     5    10    3          4          0         0
19     5    10    3          4          0         0
```

...

This is to check if there's been a gap down, and if it was subsequently filled at some point in the next 5 days. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd 

# initialize list of lists 
data = [[5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4],
         [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4],
         [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4],
         [3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3, 3], [3, 10, 3, 4],
         [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4],
         [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4],
         [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4],
         [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4], [5, 10, 3, 4]
         ] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Adj Close']) 

# Now apply a new column and put a 1 if today's opened is less than yesterday's Adj Close
df['Gap Down?'] = 0

df.loc[df['Open'] < df['Adj Close'].shift(1), 'Gap Down?'] = 1
df.loc[df['Open'] >= df['Adj Close'].shift(1), 'Gap Down?'] = 0

# print the new dataframe
print(df)

# Now make a new column that puts a 1 if the highest price in the High column from today
# and FORWARD (future) 5 days becomes >= yesterday's close
df['Gap Fill?'] = df['Gap Down?']
#first condition
e=df['Gap Down?'].eq(1)
ind=df[e].index.values.tolist()
i=0
while i<len(ind):
    #cheked of second condition
    if(df.loc[ind[i]:ind[i]+4,'High'].max()>=df.loc[ind[i-1],'Adj Close']):

        df.loc[ind[i],'Gap Fill?'] = 1
    i+=1
print(df)
```

> Output:

```
     Open  High  Low  Adj Close  Gap Down?
0      5    10    3          4          0
1      5    10    3          4          0
2      5    10    3          4          0
3      5    10    3          4          0
4      5    10    3          4          0
5      5    10    3          4          0
6      5    10    3          4          0
7      5    10    3          4          0
8      5    10    3          4          0
9      3     3    3          3          1
10     3     3    3          3          0
11     3    10    3          4          0
12     5    10    3          4          0
13     5    10    3          4          0
14     5    10    3          4          0
15     5    10    3          4          0
16     5    10    3          4          0
17     5    10    3          4          0
18     5    10    3          4          0
19     5    10    3          4          0
20     5    10    3          4          0
21     5    10    3          4          0
22     5    10    3          4          0
23     5    10    3          4          0
     Open  High  Low  Adj Close  Gap Down?  Gap Fill?
0      5    10    3          4          0          0
1      5    10    3          4          0          0
2      5    10    3          4          0          0
3      5    10    3          4          0          0
4      5    10    3          4          0          0
5      5    10    3          4          0          0
6      5    10    3          4          0          0
7      5    10    3          4          0          0
8      5    10    3          4          0          0
9      3     3    3          3          1          1
10     3     3    3          3          0          0
11     3    10    3          4          0          0
12     5    10    3          4          0          0
13     5    10    3          4          0          0
14     5    10    3          4          0          0
15     5    10    3          4          0          0
16     5    10    3          4          0          0
17     5    10    3          4          0          0
18     5    10    3          4          0          0
19     5    10    3          4          0          0
20     5    10    3          4          0          0
21     5    10    3          4          0          0
22     5    10    3          4          0          0
23     5    10    3          4          0          0
```

Using `e`, the condition 1 is checked and condition 2 is checked by the loop for all elements that meet condition 1 whose indexes are stored in `ind`. In this case there was only one, but this allows you to do it when there are several.

I think I understood what you were looking for, if the second condition is not exactly what you were asking for, you can review it and adjust the necessary values.

Comment: Sorry, I ran into an error when trying to implement it in my code. The error says: TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [1517529600000000000] of <class 'int'>.... How would I combat this?

Comment: Cancel that, I was able to use df.reset_index to make the date index an actual column in my dataframe and it works wonderfully. Thank you!